Tableview set a image as a icon without showing the path as text
I have a 4 column QtableView that I am filling from a .csv file. The first column cells shows a custom icon from a folder of images and the rest of the columns are text only. Everything works as expected but the path to the icon image is shown as text beside the image in the same cell. Is there a way to show the image only and not show the path to it?
{
QFile file("/home/image.csv");
    if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        int lineindex = 0;
        QTextStream in(&file);

        while (!in.atEnd()) {

            QStringList lineToken;
            QString fileLine = in.readLine();

            lineToken = fileLine.split(",", QString::SkipEmptyParts);

            for (int j = 0; j < lineToken.size(); j++)
            {
                QString myValue = lineToken.at(j);
                QStandardItem *lineItem = new QStandardItem(myValue);
                lineItem->setIcon(QIcon(myValue));

                modeli->setItem(lineindex, j, lineItem);
            }
            lineindex++;
        }
        file.close();
        ui->tableView->setModel(modeli);
    }
    ui->tableView->resizeRowsToContents();
}


TYPO: Just don't use myValue in the QStandardItem constructor: new QStandardItem()

If I don't use myValue in the QStandardItem constructor I don't get the text for columns 2, 3 ,4 as the model is being populated from a 4 column csv file. Can you suggest another way to approach this?

It should be quite straightforward, and you already know how to do it, since you've explained it. You said that only the first column uses the value for the icon, and the others for its display value, so the solution is obvious: add an if/else condition and check the column, if it's the first, create lineItem without using myValue for the constructor and set the icon, otherwise create it with that value in the constructor and do not set the icon.

I finally got it working. Thank you musicamante your comment got me thinking about a different way to approach this.
{
    QFile file("/home/user/images/image.csv");
    if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        int lineindex = 0;          
        QTextStream in(&file);      

        while (!in.atEnd()) {

            QStringList lineToken;
            QString fileLine = in.readLine();   

            lineToken = fileLine.split(",", QString::SkipEmptyParts);

            for (int j = 0; j < lineToken.size(); j++)
            {
                QString myValue = lineToken.at(j);
                QStandardItem *lineItem = new QStandardItem(myValue);
                QStandardItem *lineItem1 = new QStandardItem();

                QString myPath = myValue.prepend("/home/user");

                lineItem1->setIcon(QIcon(myPath));

                modeli->setItem(lineindex, 0, lineItem1);
                modeli->setItem(lineindex, j, lineItem);
            }
            lineindex++;
        }
        file.close();
        ui->tableView->setModel(modeli);
    }
    ui->tableView ->setIconSize(QSize(300, 300));
    ui->tableView->resizeRowsToContents();
    ui->tableView->resizeColumnsToContents();
}


You're welcome, but this doesn't seem very effective nor reliable, and also inconsistent with what you are asking (and my explanation): since j may also be 0, the first iteration will overwrite the item at row/column 0, 0 with lineItem (the one with myValue as its text, and without any icon). If the icon is always taken from a defined column in the csv line, then you should do as explained above (check the column within the inner for loop, then eventually create and set a different item). If the icon is assumed based on the field content, then the logic might follow as well.

In any case, the code above is inappropriate, as it will always overwrite the first item in each row, which is both wrong and pointless if done like this. Please take your time to provide a proper code, as right now your answer is invalid due to its implementation and based on the explanation in the original question.

I would say it is appropriate since it works and nothing is getting overwritten. It sets the icon in the first column without text and the text data in the second, third and fourth columns just like I wanted.

Then either the code above is inconsistent with your own, or the icon is taken from the last item of the csv. In any case, at least based on the code, yes, you're overwriting: in every iteration of the inner for loop you're always doing setItem() for the first column (the hard coded 0 of the first call), meaning that: 1. when j is 0 (first iteration) lineItem overwrites lineItem1; 2. for the following iterations, you keep creating and overwriting the item in the first column (set in previous iterations) with the new lineItem1. It may work for you, but it's inefficient.
